# How to detect a device on a network with a static ip?

Tags: networking

Assume a router with the ip 192.168.0.1, and a desktop computer connected to this router with the ip 192.168.0.2. This ip was given to the desktop via dhcp. I have access to the router and can view the list of dhcp leases.

Now assume that someone connects a new computer to the router. This new system has dhcp disabled, and in the OS is it assigned a static ip of 192.168.0.3.

From either the router or the desktop, how could I discover that this new machine is connected to the network? (Assume icmp is disabled and the new system has no open ports)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The machine will be sending ARP queries for devices it wants to talk to (in particular the local gateway) – you can capture them using Wireshark or tcpdump.

Those devices will also ARP in order to deliver responses, and the machine's MAC and IP addresses will show up in their neighbor caches (ARP caches). Your local gateway's ARP cache will usually have pretty much all devices within the subnet (though not necessarily all at once). Use `ip neigh` or `arp -a -n` to list it; many routers will have some form of "ARP table" somewhere. There is a similar neighbor cache for IPv6 NDP as well.

If the machine itself stays completely quiet, you can use network scanners which send out ARP probes to every possible address in the subnet. (Scanning an IPv4 /24 takes a few blinks.) There are many such tools, but nmap is the only one I remember offhand.

There's also `arping` for making directed ARP queries if the IP address is already known – it's like ping but for ARP. (The IPv6 equivalent might be `ndisc6`.)